# showing an img in a div after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to upload an image with javascript and display it in a div but the method I'm using right now is not working. I tried using both an img tag and just setting it as a background-image but both won't show the img in the div but when I inspect the div it shows that the URL has successfully been inserted. Where did I go wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const image_input = document.querySelector("#image_input");
image_input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const uploaded_image = reader.result;
    $('.imgCon').attr("background-image", `url(${uploaded_image})`);
    $('.imgCon2 img').attr("src", `url(${uploaded_image})`);
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

```css
.imgCon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;
  /* background-size: 100%; */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.imgCon2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #000000;
  /* background-size: 100%; */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" title="" id="image_input" accept="image/png, image/jpg">

<div class="imgCon">
</div>

<div class="imgCon2">
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

Comment: How are you submitting? I would add an onChange to your input and have it run the function.

Comment: yeah im going to do that, this was just a rough sketch @Mizzy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
$('.imgCon').css("background-image", `url(${uploaded_image})`);
$('.imgCon2 img').attr("src", uploaded_image);
```

`attr` will set an attribute on the element i.e `<div background-image="url(...)"` and `src="url(...)"` is incorrect.